# How to get country group/country/region using Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to retrieve all country/country group/ region using Facebook API. And with every country i want to have the number of people. Please take a look to the screenshot bellow.

[image]